# Curl in c++ on mac OSX with https causing segmentation fault via valgrind

Tags: c++, macos, curl, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I try to send via curl request from c++ on my macOS (for example on linux works everything fine). But when I run the program via valgrind and then try to send request over curl then the program fails with a segmentation fault. Even on code from here https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html and I also try the curl command from terminal with valgrind and even then it failed but it must be https. I tried the curl with openssl and darwinssl but without success. 
My os is macOS high sierra.

**The output from valgrind:**

```
valgrind ./demo 

==78893== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==78893== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==78893== Using Valgrind-3.14.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==78893== Command: ./demo
==78893== 
--78893-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./demo" warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
--78893-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--78893-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--78893-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
--78893-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 8 times)
==78893== Thread 2:
==78893== Invalid read of size 4
==78893==    at 0x100AB45BA: _pthread_body (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==78893==    by 0x100AB450C: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==78893==    by 0x100AB3BF8: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==78893==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==78893== 
==78893== 
==78893== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==78893==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==78893==    at 0x100AB45BA: _pthread_body (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==78893==    by 0x100AB450C: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==78893==    by 0x100AB3BF8: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==78893==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==78893==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==78893==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==78893==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==78893==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==78893== 
==78893== HEAP SUMMARY:
==78893==     in use at exit: 840,095 bytes in 3,760 blocks
==78893==   total heap usage: 4,784 allocs, 1,024 frees, 1,520,703 bytes allocated
==78893== 
==78893== LEAK SUMMARY:
==78893==    definitely lost: 5,792 bytes in 78 blocks
==78893==    indirectly lost: 416 bytes in 12 blocks
==78893==      possibly lost: 4,648 bytes in 111 blocks
==78893==    still reachable: 208,644 bytes in 3,290 blocks
==78893==         suppressed: 620,595 bytes in 269 blocks
==78893== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==78893== 
==78893== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==78893== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 25 from 4) Segmentation fault: 11
```

Also you can try write to command line: "valgrind curl https://example.com"
It causing same exception.

Comment: You are building Valgrind from source? Can you share the source for your demo app?

Comment: Nope curl is builded from source also I tried from brew and standart curl system lib. Valgrind is used only for check the memory of curl (and valgrind is installed via brew). And the source code of the app which I tested Is from this page  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html . And this causing the above issue. But it shouldn`t because on another platform (linux, windows) is works correct.

Comment: Finnaly I solved it by using curl 7.46.0. Even 7.49.0 did the same problem. Fortunatelly 7.46.0 is good.